# what does this will do in C programing: ++group[ (int) (value[i]+0.5)/10]

Tags: c, arrays

Following code  is example of how to confirm if number entered is in specific range or not.

For example if I enter number say N then I want increment counter which says if it is in range of:

1-10
11-20
...
91-100

```
Here is the code snip from one of the text book:


#define MAXVAL 50
#define COUNTER 11
main ()
{
float value[MAXVAL];
int i, low, high;
static group[COUNTER] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

*/READING AND COUNTING*/

for(i=0; i<MAXVAL; i++)
{
/* READING OF VALUES*/

scanf("%f", &value[i]);

/* COUNTING FREQUENCY OF GROUPS */

++group[ (int) (value[i]+0.5)/10]  <<< I would like to understand how this will find if number is in specific ranges?

/* PRINTING OF FREQUENCY TABLE */

printf("\n");
printf(" GROUP RANGE FREQUENCY\N\N");

for(i=0; i< COUNTER; i++)
{
low = i*10;
if (i==10)
high =100;
else 
high=low + 9;
printf( " %2d %3dto%3d %d)\n", i+1, low,high,group[i]);

}

}
```

What does this will do in  above C program: ++group[ (int) (value[i]+0.5)/10]

Thanks

Comment: and what if the number is 10.5?  Your ranges have gaps in them.

Comment: You should vote on the answers, on no one will reply to future answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break it down for understanding it.

read `++group[ (int) (value[i]+0.5)/10]` as:
I want to increment the index of group array by 1.
Which index?
It somehow depends on the value entered by user (value[i])
Why add 0.5 to it?
To round a floating number. more specifically to take the ceil() of that number
Why divide by 10?
Because your groups are of size 10.

Example:
User enters 11.
value[i] = 11 (float)
11 + 0.5 = 11.5 (float)
11.5 / 10 = 1.15 (float)
typecast 1.15 to int = 1 (int)
++group[1], increments group[1] by 1 and shows that 11 falls in group 1 i.e. 10 - 19

Another example:
User enters 9.
value[i] = 9 (float)
9 + 0.5 = 9.5 (float)
9.5 / 10 = 0.95 (float)
typecast 0.95 to int = 0 (int)
++group[0], increments group[0] by 1 and shows that 9 falls in group 0 i.e. 0 - 9

Another example:
User enters 9.1.
value[i] = 9.1 (float)
9.1 + 0.5 = 9.6 (float)
9.6 / 10 = 0.96 (float)
typecast 0.95 to int = 1 (int)
++group[1], increments group[1] by 1 and shows that 9.1 falls in group 1 i.e. 10 - 19

Note:
According to the code, your groups are 0-9, 10 - 19 ... and not 1 - 10, 11 - 20

Comment: so ++group[1] is actually incrementing the value stored in location 1 of array? then only this should be possible to achieve?

Comment: yes it `++group[1]` increments the value stored at location 1 of array. This is not the only option. If you break down the solution, see how that 1 in group[1] was calculated? It was done so because the input given by user was such. If the input is say 57, the steps would be (57 + 0.5) / 10 = 5.75 => typecast to int gives 5, so ++group[5] will come into effect. i.e. group 50-59

Comment: I hope I answered your question. If you have more questions, please feel free to type it down here.

Comment: In your case ++group[num] is same as group[num]++ or group[num] = group[num] + 1

Comment: Yeah looks like I got the logic. Thanks all for help. However one last thing Can I use (int) any where in any key word to make sure output is converted to integer?

Comment: yes. you can use it pretty much anywhere. This is called typecasting. The syntax for doing to is int value = (int)<an expression or variable that you want to convert to integer>

Answer (score 1):

Examine the index of the group array:

```
[(int) (value[i]+0.5)/10]
```

This effectively takes the value scanned in from console input, adds .50, divide the sum by 10, then convert to an int. The better question is *why do this at all*?

The addition of 0.50 is to account for rounding. If `value[i]` is at or above a marign of 0.50 (such as `1.51, 2.50, 3.99`, etc) this forces it to the next whole number (`2.01, 3.00, 4.49`).

Next, the division by 10. This apparently assumes the values being input are between 0.00 and exclusively less than 109.50. Dividing by 10 ensures these values will be between 0.00 and 10.00. This will, of course **not** work as soon as the console input is greater than 109.50.

Then the cast to (int). Straight forward enough. Kill the fraction off the float and manufacture your int.

Finally, assuming the input *was* in fact between 0.00 and exclusively less than 109.50, the counter matching the requisite range in the group[] array will be incremented by one.

Bottom line, it is a poor mechanism for trying to cluster input values into groups and updating counters within he appropriate range, and it will choke as soon as the input value is > 109.50.

Comment: so what could be the best way to do it? I have to define various ranges and compare them one by one to put them in to appropriate ranges?

Comment: @user1504633 The entire thing can be made to work as written so long as the *input values* of values[] are **range checked** for what they're about to be used for (indexes into a known-fixed array). Boundary check them *prior* to using them.

Comment: Yeah, comparing upto some arrays will okay but if ranges will increase then there will be issue.

Comment: actually I think I got the point of usage or may be similar logic, here I have initialized array to count if value in specific range or not... for example if value is in 0 to 10 range then 9+0.5 = 9.5/10 = 0.95 rounds up to 0 or 1 which will increment by ++group... same way if value is 19 then 19+0.5=19.5/10 is 1.9 which is rounded to 1 and have that position of array value incremented. so when I will check which number is in 0-10 or 11-20 then I will be checking value at group array location 0 and 1... does it sounds appropriate?

Comment: @user1504633 It sounds like you probably get it now. the ranges are [0.00, 9.50), [9.50, 19.50), [19.50, 29.50), etc... though [99.50, 109.50). Note that all the tail values on those ranges are **exclusive**, while all the head values of those ranges are **inclusive**.

Answer (score 0):

um something like this:

Assuming `group[0] = 0->10, group[1] = 11->20, group[2] = 21->30..`
take an example float: `10.3`

Applying the formula there, `10.8/10 ~= 1`. Hence its in the range **10->20**.

Take another example: **22.4**

Applying the formula there, `(22.4 + 0.5)/10 ~= 22.9/10 = 2`. Hence its in the range `20->30`. And so on. It will work for `high = 100` and `low = 0`.

Comment: what is use of (int) in ++group[ (int) (value[i]+0.5)/10]? conversion to integer?

Comment: @user1504633 converts a double to integer. arrays dont accept double/float values as subscript

Comment: that one increments the value at group[i]

Answer (score 0):

`++group[ (int) (value[i]+0.5)/10]` is

- taking the float input value `value[i]`,
- rounding it to an int `(int) (value[i]+0.5)`
- then dividing it by 10 to get a group index, and then
- adding 1 `++group[...]` to the group it belongs to.

In other words it is computing the number of values that fall between 0..9, 10..19, 20..29, ... 100..109, 110..119

This code is completely **unsafe**.  If the input value is greater that than COUNTER * 10 or negative, then random bytes of memory will be written.  Throw this code away or place some safety checks into it.

**EDIT**

Safety check, ignore input values that are out of range.

```
int g = (int) (value[i]+0.5) /10]
if (0 <= g && g < COUNT)
  ++group[g];
```

Comment: any suggestion on improvement or logic?